# Google script batching rows over multiple sheets to speed up processing

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, hide

I've been trying to figure out some of the **batching** techniques in Google Sheets that came so easily in Excel.

On a workbook with 22 tabs, the first 12 tabs are named for the months of the year. I'm trying to **auto-hide certain rows that start with a blank in column A only in these first 12 tabs**.

My current script is very slow since it is calculating line by line.

I want to select the data on **rows 5 through 94** on the **first 12 tabs** named JAN, FEB, etc., excluding the remaining tabs prior to the calculations being run. I can't seem to get a handle on the array function, if that's even the best technique.

Any help you could offer batching these rows would be greatly appreciated.

```
function hideRows() {
["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"].forEach(function (s) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName(s)
    sheet.unhideRow(sheet.getRange('A1:X94'))  
    sheet.getRange('A1:X94')
    sheet.getRange('A1:X94')
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (!r[0]) sheet.hideRows(i + 1)
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by column A, batch-hide the rows, then unsort.

```
function hideRows() {

  var sheet, range, values, row, col95, // col95 will be a helper column that will unsort back to the original order. 
      arr95 = []; // this array will hold the values for col95

  for (i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
    arr95.push([i + 1]);
  }

  ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"].forEach(function (s) {
    sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName(s);

    sheet.insertColumnAfter(1); // this column, used for sorting, will be deleted at the end.
    col95 = sheet.getRange("B1:B95");
    col95.setValues(arr95);

    range = sheet.getRange('1:94'); // don't specify A1:X94 in case you have data in Column Y
    range.sort(1);
    range = sheet.getRange('1:94');
    sheet.unhideRow(range);
    values = range.getValues();

    row = 94; // resetting row to a neutral number 
    for (r = 0, i = 0; r < values.length; r++) {
      if (!values[r][0]) {
        row = r + 1;
        break; // as soon as we get an empty A-cell, the row is set and the loop ends.
      }
    }

    if (row < 94) sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(row + ':94')); // batch-hiding all rows with an empty col A
    range = sheet.getRange('1:94');
    range.sort(2);
    sheet.deleteColumn(2); // the unsorting column is deleted.
  });
}
```

This is the batch-hiding line:

```
    if (row < 94) sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(row + ':94')); // batch-hiding all rows with an empty col A
```

Compared to the original code, this code reduces runtime by a factor of 10x in my tests. The trade-off is that it is not as concise.

Comment: That batch-hiding line may be exactly what I needed to make this work. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey your code ran for 135 seconds. I managed to execute the code in my answer in under 13 seconds. Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

The `forEach` seems overused here. Also, the script takes a very unusual structure.

Assuming it will always be the **first** 12 sheets and you either do not care the order the data appears in or have a column you can sort by

```
function hideRows() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  var count

  for (count = 0; count < 12; count++) {
    // sort the sheet by column A ascending to get all empty cells at the bottom
    sheets[count].sort(1,true)

    // find out the last row with data on column A
    var lastRow = sheets[count].getRange('A5:A94').getLastRow() 

    // hide all rows bellow the last data row. You need to add 1 for the first empty row and 5 more because we skipped a few when getting the range
    sheets[count].hideRows(lastRow + 6, 94 - lastRow)

   // If you don't care how it's sorted leave it, or sort by the correct column here
  }
}
```

This should batch everything as much as possible calling SpreadsheetApp as little as possible. I did not test this code, just wrote it straight here, so you might want to check a few things (like wether ascending will put empty rows on bottom or top) and the calculation of `hideRows` indexes.

**EDIT:** just checked that `getLastRow()` will return the last index of the selected range, not the last row with actual data, so if your range is `A5:A94` then it will return `94` so it works slightly differently then if it was for a sheet. But you can simply run a `for` to check for an empty string against the array of values, should still be faster as you only need to find when the values stop.

Comment: thanks so much. this would be perfect if it only affected rows 5 through 94

Comment: @Vytautas the `.getLastRow` method only returns the last row of the *sheet*, so it does not work to get the last row of a range as you intended.

Comment: @AntoineColson that is incorrect. There is a difference between `sheet.getLastRow()` and `range.getLastRow()`. The first one is as you said for the last row in a sheet. However, if you run `getLastRow()` against a `Range` class it will limit the last row to that specific range. You can see these 2: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow() and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastRow()

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Also I just saw your edit to your answer, thanks. I was testing it and obviously it didn't work. Now we know why!